# Use PHP ternary in Yii2 Html::a tag

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table with objects. For each one I want to display the font-awesome icon ' class fa fa-toggle-on' if it is released, otherwise 'class fa fa-toggle-off'. This is the last column in the table.
Below, my code I'm trying for that column:

```
<td>
<?php echo Html::a('<i class='<?=($object->is_released == true) ? 'fa fa-toggle-on' : 'fa fa- 
toggle- off';?>'</i>', ['objects/release', 'id' => $object->id], [
'title' => 'Released',
'onclick' =>""
]) ?> 
</td>
```

This is not at all finished, but I can't get the php ternary operator to work. It does not interpret it at all, it seems, probably because I don't know the correct syntax here. Or could I do it with Javascript?
Very thankful for help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already in PHP tag, so you need concatenation:

```
<td>
<?php echo Html::a('<i class="'.(($object->is_released == true) ? 'fa fa-toggle-on' : 'fa fa-toggle-off').'"></i>', ['objects/release', 'id' => $object->id], [
'title' => 'Released',
'onclick' =>""
]) ?> 
</td>
```

Comment: ..and same to you, also working! Thank you for spending time on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>
<?php echo Html::a('<i class="'.($object->is_released ? 'fa fa-toggle-on' : 'fa fa-toggle-off').'"></i>', ['objects/release', 'id' => $object->id], [
'title' => 'Released',
'onclick' =>""
]) ?> 
</td>
```